# Proof of $dE = T dS − P dV + µdN$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, entropy

I'm following [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030024288). The author states The First Law of Thermodynamics as follows:

> $$dE = đQ + đW + đC$$ , (3.50)
> where

> – đQ = energy put into the system thermally by an environment, such
> as a stove;

> – đW = mechanical work performed on the system by forces arising
> from pressure, electromagnetism, etc.;

> – đC = energy brought into the system, either by particles that arrive
> as a result of environmental changes, or by the environment itself.
> This includes large-scale potential energy, such as that due to gravity
> when we are treating a large system such as an atmosphere.

where $dE$ is the infinitesimal increase in a system’s internal energy.

Then he goes on to replace $đQ$ with $TdS$ using the following argument:

> In Section 3.8 we found that entropy is extensive: the total entropy of a
> set of interacting systems is always the sum of the systems’ individual entropies, even though this total entropy grows as the systems evolve toward
> equilibrium. Indeed, **at constant volume and particle number** (i.e., for thermal interactions only), the First Law says $dE = đQ$, whereas (3.141) says
> $dE = T dS$. We infer that $T dS$ is the desired replacement for $đQ$ that makes
> for an exact-differential-only quasi-static version of the First Law. Replacing the “heat into the system”, $đQ$, with $T dS$ is something that we already
> saw and used in the discussion around Figure 3.13. We might replace dE
> with $đQ$ in that discussion and observe that, whereas we certainly can write
> $đQ_1 = T_1 dS_1$ and $đQ_2 = T_2 dS_2$
> , we cannot write “$đQ = T dS$” for the entire
> evolving system. So, the quasi-static version of the First Law using only exact
> differentials applies individually to each subsystem, but not to the combined
> system, because it is only the subsystems that are always held very close to
> equilibrium.

I don't understand this because it seems like it will work only for constant volume and particle number and also it is known that $đQ = TdS$ is true only for reversible processes, so we can't infer that $dE = T dS − P dV + µdN$ holds in general.
Also, if the book's reasoning is indeed not well-founded, how to actually prove this?

*Edit: I highlighted the exact place where the assumption about constant volume is made. I don't understand how we can then proceed to conclude that something is true for any quasi-static process.*

Comment: Please use MathJax and the quote function. That's not the first time you were told to do so. There is no benefit in using screenshots/images here.

Comment: The fragment that you quote only claims that the equation is true for quasistatic (reversible processes.) $dW$ and $dC$ were apparently dealt with earlier in the book. Also note that this is restatement of the energy conservation law.

Comment: Quasistatic is not a synonym of reversible. And this still doesn't explain the justification author made based on constant volume and particle number, it seems like he just used a specific situation

Comment: Take two isolated systems in equilibirum,"1" and "2", say $T_1 <T_2$ having initial entropies $S_1$ and $S_2$. Bring them together and let them interact thermally but stay isolated together from everything else. System "1" gains $dS_1$ and system "2" loses $dS_2$, but when equilibrium is achieved the total system entropy is $S_1+S_2 +dS$ where $dS_1+dS_2<dS$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I added the quotes, although I still find screenshots better-looking :)

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, but I think it does not really matter what you think is better looking (and IIRC, I've sent you a list of reasons why MathJax etc. is preferred over images and screenshots). We, as a community, want that users use MathJax. Regarding your question: Energy is a state function; think about that...

Comment: I see that energy is a state function, but I also see the assumption author made about constant volume and number of particles

Comment: yes, if the only interaction is thermal, i.e., no work, then all changes in $"TdS"$ is the change in internal energy , that is an exact differential $dE=TdS$. This is why we can use calorimeters and be able to associate the change in the thermometer reading with change in entropy and internal energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct, the quoted text is not an entirely convincing and clear argument for validity of the relation $dU = TdS - PdV+\mu N$ in homogeneous simple systems, in general.

One way to make such an argument is this: any equilibrium state with defined quantities $U,S,V,N$ can be reached from the reference state by some reversible process, in which $dQ = TdS$ holds all along (which we know from Clausius), and also $dW = -pdV$ holds all along. Consequently, one can define $S$ and $U$ at any equilibrium state of the system, and then $U$ is function of $S,V,N$, and for any infinitesimal variation of $S,V,N$ in the space of thermodynamics states, we have the mathematical relation from multivariate calculus:

$$
dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}_{V,N}\bigg|dS + \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg|_{S,N}dV + \frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\bigg|_{S,V}dN.
$$

This is valid for any process where $U,S,V,N$ and the corresponding derivatives are defined all along, even for those processes which are not entirely reversible.

Further physics arguments identify

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\bigg|_{V,N} = T,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg|_{S,N} = -p,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\bigg|_{S,V} = \mu.
$$

Thus $dQ=TdS$ can be valid even for irreversible processes, provided the variables change in such a way that they are defined all along at all stages of the process. This is when the process can be represented as a curve in the space of thermodynamic equilibrium states. For example, if heat transfer is over a non-zero temperature difference outside the system, but inside the system, temperature is uniform, then $dQ=TdS$, even though the process as a whole is irreversible.

Answer (score 2):

Typically we have $dQ = TdS$, as provided by Clausius' inequality, and an analysis of entropy as path independent. The way I understand this is that a transfer of heat is *always* associated with a corresponding change in entropy, which is scaled by the temperature of the exchange.

In Enrico Fermi's very old book *Thermodynamics* there is a very satisfactory derivation of this differential of entropy via a thought experiment which uses a system receiving/releasing heat to a series of Carnot cycles.

But in Reichl's *Introduction to Thermodynamics* he does state the following:

$$TdS \geq dQ$$

Reference, equation $(2.56)$, 2nd edition.

His statement is that the equality holds for reversible processes and the inequality holds for spontaneous or irreversible processes.

He also uses the term *entropy production*  to account for this extra entropy:

$$dS = d_i S + \frac{dQ}{T}$$

Where $d_i S$ is zero for a reversible process.

In other words: entropy can increase for *other reasons* besides a direct transfer of heat. Entropy is a measure of disorder, so there are transformations which involve a bigger change in this disorder other than the heat transfer itself.